# What is a good roadmap to learn Shiva Visistadvaita philosophy?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, shaivism, brahma-sutras, srikanthacharya

I want to learn about Śrikānth Acharya's Shiva Visistadvaita.

What is a good place to start for a beginner? I don't have any background in any philosophy before. Any resources, references and ideas are welcome.

Namah Shivay